# How to mount an external USB drive on a Sony Z3?

Tags: usb-on-the-go, sony-xperia-z3

I have a **Sony Z3** which is supposed to support OTG and therefore it should be possible to use an external flash drive. However I can't find the "Detect USB drive" quick setting which is supposed to enable the flash drive once it's connected in the USB port.

Is there any setting I need to toggle in order to mount the USB drive?

I'm using stock Android 5.1.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out some versions of the Sony Z3 don't support OTG drives. Therefore no software/hardware change can allow you to use external USB devices.

Upgrading to Android 6.0 didn't help either, so I've abandoned the idea.